# Ubikloadpack jmeter plugins not attached show error on command like that:

Tags: javascript, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

[image]

Ubik Load Pack Jmeter Plugins not support why ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a text version of the error instead of a link to an external image. Also, as suggested in your error, you should be using non-GUI mode for load testing. Can you show us what you are using and trying to do to hit this error?

Comment: cbfxm-vvrug.png ... That is error show how to slove